# Syntax error using reduce() in puppet class

Tags: puppet, reduce

I am trying to figure out whether my host has any of the ips in the `$target_node_ips` array

```
$is_target_node = $target_node_ips.reduce(false) |$memo, $entry| { has_ip_address($entry) or $memo }
```

however this leads to the following error

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Syntax error at '.'; expected '}' at service.pp:44
```

Can anybody shed some light on what's wrong? Both puppet master and the client run puppet 3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I just figured out that `reduce()` is [experimental in 3.2](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/3/reference/lang_experimental_3_2.html) and it requires the future parser to be enabled for it to work.